# How to check if a Laravel eloquest relation is eagerLoaded on the retrieved event of a model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, traits, eager-loading

I will try to simplify the problem as much as I can.

I want to disable a relation load from a trait on a resource that happens at the `retrieved` event.

There is a model we will name `Post` that uses a trait named `HasComments`.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    use HasComments;

    ...
}
```

The trait listenes for the `retrieved` event on the model and loads the `comments` relation.

```
trait HasComment
{
    public static function bootHasComment(): void
    {
        self::retrieved(function ($model) {
            $model->load('comments');
        });
    }

    public function comments(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to check if the `comments` relation was eager loaded and NOT load the relation again.

I tried to check if the relation is loaded but failed.

ex:

```
self::retrieved(function ($model) {
    if (!isset($model->relations['comments'])) {
        dd('still loads!');
        $model->load('comments');
    }
});
```

or

```
self::retrieved(function ($model) {
    if (!$model->relationLoaded('comments')) {
        dd('still loads!');
        $model->load('comments');
    }
});
```

I was also thinking of maybe there is a way to disable this behavior when constructin the query but failed again.

ex:

```
trait HasComment
{
    public bool $load = true;

    public static function bootHasComment(): void
    {

        self::retrieved(function ($model) {
            if (!$this->load) {
                dd('still loads!');
                $model->load('comments');
            }
        });
    }

    public function comments(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class);
    }

    public function disableRetrievedLoad()
    {
        $this->load = false;
    }
}
```

Has someone encountered something similar and can give me some help?

Comment: I recommend using [PHP Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to find out exactly which queries are being executed in your pages.

Comment: may be you can use a static variable to switch on demand the behavior of `bootHasComment` method

Comment: Checkout `loadMissing` so `$model->loadMissing('comments');`  which loads a relationship only when it has not already been loaded. [Laravel reference](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)

Comment: In your callback of `self::retrieved` it is not `$this->load` but `$model->load` you need to ask. The context of the callback function doesn't overload into the models (object) scope context automatically.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method named [`relationLoaded`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php#L820-L823) that returns a boolean. Seems like the right fit for your needs.

Alternatively, if you want to load a relationship if it's not been loaded yet, there's [`loadMissing`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L734-L741).

```php
$post = Post::first();
$post->relationLoaded('comments'); // false
$post->loadMissing('comments');    // makes the queries to load the relationship
$post->relationLoaded('comments'); // true
$post->loadMissing('comments');    // does nothing. comments is already loaded
```